# Two divs stacked on top of one another, but both must be clickable, hoverable and/or scrollable?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, css-selectors

I have a code similar to the one below where two divs of equal width and height with absolute positioning are placed inside a parent div (`.container`).
I would like for both of them to be clickable, hoverable and/or scrollable, but as it is, only the top one is.
I tried `pointer-events:none`, but it makes the div unclicklable.
I also tried `isolation: isolate` but I may be implementing it wrong because I couldn't get it to work.
Any help is much appreciated!

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.scrollable {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.hoverable {
  color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.hoverable:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget augue elit. Nullam eget augue vel odio feugiat malesuada. Suspendisse ultrices, lacus nec finibus varius, ipsum tortor mattis urna, ut tincidunt nibh ex eu ipsum. Ut et neque vitae urna euismod placerat vel in enim.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget augue elit. Nullam eget augue vel odio feugiat malesuada. Suspendisse ultrices, lacus nec finibus varius, ipsum tortor mattis urna, ut tincidunt nibh ex eu ipsum. Ut et neque vitae urna euismod placerat vel in enim.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget augue elit. Nullam eget augue vel odio feugiat malesuada. Suspendisse ultrices, lacus nec finibus varius, ipsum tortor mattis urna, ut tincidunt nibh ex eu ipsum. Ut et neque vitae urna euismod placerat vel in enim.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget augue elit. Nullam eget augue vel odio feugiat malesuada. Suspendisse ultrices, lacus nec finibus varius, ipsum tortor mattis urna, ut tincidunt nibh ex eu ipsum. Ut et neque vitae urna euismod placerat vel in enim.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="hoverable">
    <h2>Hover me!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the purpose of having two divs directly on top of each other. Maybe you could try to use the `scrollable` in combination with `hover`. I would definitely avoid two divs directly on top of each other. Maybe `pseudo-elements` can also help you achieve what you're trying to do with two stacked divs.

Nonetheless, regarding your question: I think it is somewhat possible, but quite hacky and I wouldn't really recommend it. As you can see in the example, it works somehow by playing around with `pointer-events`, but it is neither accessible nor really a good solution.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.scrollable {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.hoverable {
  color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: all;  
}

.hoverable:hover {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget augue elit. Nullam eget augue vel odio feugiat malesuada. Suspendisse ultrices, lacus nec finibus varius, ipsum tortor mattis urna, ut tincidunt nibh ex eu ipsum. Ut et neque vitae urna euismod placerat vel in enim.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget augue elit. Nullam eget augue vel odio feugiat malesuada. Suspendisse ultrices, lacus nec finibus varius, ipsum tortor mattis urna, ut tincidunt nibh ex eu ipsum. Ut et neque vitae urna euismod placerat vel in enim.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget augue elit. Nullam eget augue vel odio feugiat malesuada. Suspendisse ultrices, lacus nec finibus varius, ipsum tortor mattis urna, ut tincidunt nibh ex eu ipsum. Ut et neque vitae urna euismod placerat vel in enim.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget augue elit. Nullam eget augue vel odio feugiat malesuada. Suspendisse ultrices, lacus nec finibus varius, ipsum tortor mattis urna, ut tincidunt nibh ex eu ipsum. Ut et neque vitae urna euismod placerat vel in enim.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="hoverable">
    <h2>Hover me!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```